# Store a JSON in a drop down menu as value

Tags: javascript, flask

I have some JSON data I want to be able to select from in a drop down menu, but I can't manage to retreive clean data after it's been selected.

my data :

```
graphs = [
           {
            "data":{some dictionary}
            "name":graphX
           }
           { ...
           }
         ]
```

my html :

```
<select id='dd-menu'>
    {% for graph in graphs %}
        <option value={{graph.data}}>{{graph.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

my js :

```
var e = document.getElementById('dd-menu');
var topologyData = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
```

When I load my page, my value seems all corrupted in the browser inspector

```
option value = {u&#39;someKeyu&#39;:someValue ... }
```

I don't know if it's from python2.7 encoding weirdness or because I don't load do it properly

Comment: <option value="{{json.dumps(graph.data)}}">{{graph.name}}</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the data to a JSON string when rendering it.

```
{{ graph.data|tojson }}
```

Comment: I have a `jinja2.exceptions.UndifinedError` now, `json is undefined` (I imported json in my main.py)

Comment: You also need to import json...check if you did it correctly

Comment: I already imported json in my flask main. I can succesfuly load some json with `json.load` in my flask main. (I load my data this way)